# Check if domain class' hasmany collection contains the subset collection

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, criteria, grails-2.0

Hello i'm trying to get list of domain objects if a domain object's `hasmany` association contains all elements in given list.

```
class Patient {
   static hasMany = [symptoms:Symptom]
}
class Symptom {
}
```

Looking for something similar to `containsAll()` but can be usable in criteria would be awesome. But i can't find it myself. I was hoping criteria would let me do this:

```
Patient.createCriteria().list {
    'containsAll'('symptoms',listOfSymptoms)
}
```

Comment: If you run the query with the list statement instead of listDistinct, does it work? Just to check where the problem is.

Comment: Yes the last piece of code works and does exactly it is supposed to do. The problem is i can't find the equivalent of criteria expression of list.containsAll(subset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in HQL (less verbose) and yes there is no `containsAll` functionality in Criteria.

```
    Patient.executeQuery(
"FROM Patient p WHERE p IN 
(SELECT s.patient from Symptom s WHERE s.id = :id1) 
AND p IN 
(SELECT s.patient from Symptom s WHERE s.id = :id2) 
AND p IN 
(SELECT s.patient from Symptom s WHERE s.id = :id3)", 
[id1: 1, id2: 2, id3: 3])
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can i construct this query if i had just a collection(`List` or `Set`) of `id`s

Answer (score 0):

Have found a way to do it without criteria or hql. But i have no idea what happens when Patient table has millions of rows of data. It might get ugly.

```
Patient.list().findAll{
    it.symptoms.containsAll(listOfSymptoms)
}
```

or id can be used like this:

```
Patient.list().findAll{
    it.symptoms*.id.containsAll(listOfSymptomIds)
}
```

Comment: I could not convince myself to suggest you the same thing you are doing here. The complexity increases in this case. `.list()` traverses the whole table and returns all rows, `findAll` traverses all the rows again, `symptoms*.id` traverses all `symptoms`, and finally `containsAll` destroys the rest. :). I could have suggested the same but I wanted your application to survive without starvation. :) Try to add some thousands of records to `Patient` and `Symptom` and see the difference.

Comment: Yes, it works painfully slow :D. Can you show me how to construct that query string with given list of `id`s?